# Java streams .orElseThrow

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I want convert a piece of code from a Connection Pool project i have been working on to use streams

the original code is

```
for (Map.Entry<JdbConnection,Instant> entry : borrowed.entrySet()) {
  Instant leaseTime = entry.getValue();
  JdbConnection jdbConnection = entry.getKey();
  Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(leaseTime, Instant.now());
  if (timeElapsed.toMillis() > leaseTimeInMillis) {
    //expired, let's close it and remove it from the map
    jdbConnection.close();
    borrowed.remove(jdbConnection);

    //create a new one, mark it as borrowed and give it to the client
    JdbConnection newJdbConnection = factory.create();
    borrowed.put(newJdbConnection,Instant.now());
    return newJdbConnection;
  }
}

throw new ConnectionPoolException("No connections available");
```

I have got to the point of this

```
borrowed.entrySet().stream()
                   .filter(entry -> Duration.between(entry.getValue(), Instant.now()).toMillis() > leaseTimeInMillis)
                   .findFirst()
                   .ifPresent(entry -> {
                     entry.getKey().close();
                     borrowed.remove(entry.getKey());
                   });


JdbConnection newJdbConnection = factory.create();
borrowed.put(newJdbConnection,Instant.now());
return newJdbConnection;
```

The above can compile but the moment i add `orElseThrow` after `IfPresent` i am getting the following

```
/home/prakashs/connection_pool/src/main/java/com/spakai/ConnectionPool.java:83: error: void cannot be dereferenced
                       .orElseThrow(ConnectionPoolException::new);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because `ifPresent` returns void. It can't be chained. You could do something like:

```
Entry<JdbConnection, Instant> entry =
    borrowed.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> Duration.between(entry.getValue(), Instant.now())
                            .toMillis() > leaseTimeInMillis)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(ConnectionPoolException::new));
entry.getKey().close();
borrowed.remove(entry.getKey());
```

What you were looking for would read well:

```
.findFirst().ifPresent(value -> use(value)).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

But for it to work, `ifPresent` would have to return the `Optional`, which would be a little odd. It would mean you could chain one `ifPresent` after another, doing multiple operations on the value. That might have been a good design, but it isn't the one the creators of `Optional` went with.

Comment: I would recommend `findAny` instead of `findFirst`

Comment: For those wondering about @JeanValjean suggestion, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35359112/3136474).

Comment: @Dinei FWIW, the reason I stuck to `findFirst` was because OP used `findFirst` in the question. I don't know if OP had any special reason for doing so, but I didn't want to just arbitrarily change it to `findAny`. Of course, `findAny` is a performance win on parallel streams when you can really accept any match, and not just the first.

Comment: Perfectly fair @DavidConrad, I just wanted to add further information I had to dig up.

Answer (score 2):

Use map instead of isPresent, and return with an Optional instead of an exception.

```
borrowed.entrySet().stream()
               .filter(entry -> Duration.between(entry.getValue(), Instant.now()).toMillis() > leaseTimeInMillis)
               .findFirst()
               .map(entry -> {
                 entry.getKey().close();
                 borrowed.remove(entry.getKey());
                 JdbConnection newJdbConnection = factory.create();
                 borrowed.put(newJdbConnection,Instant.now());
                 return newJdbConnection;
               })
```