# Java 8 Stream to find element in list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
public class Item {
    int id;
    String name;
    // few other fields, contructor, getters and setters
}
```

I have a list of Items. I want to iterate through the list and find the instance which has a particular id. I'm trying to do it through streams.

```
public void foobar() {

    List<Item> items = getItemList();
    List<Integer> ids = getIdsToLookup();
    int id, i = ids.size() - 1;

    while (i >= 0) {
        id = ids.get(i);
        Optional<Item> item = items
            .stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getId() == id)
            .findFirst();
        // do stuff
        i--;
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to iterate over the list and get the element I need? Also, I get an error on the filter line for id which says variables used in lambda expressions must be final or effectively final. Maybe I can define id inside the while loop, that should get rid of the exception. Thanks.

Comment: You're using the same variable i for the index in the list, and for the current item in the lambda. Choose a different name. That code is fine, but quite inefficient. If you have multiple ids and need to find the corresponding item for all, start by creating a HashMap<Integer, Item>, and then use the HashMap.

Comment: I'm using a different variable in my code, I was trying to simplify the code here. I'll change it.

Comment: Declare the variable `id` **inside** the loop, and it will be effectively final. By being outside, you reinitialize it at each iteration, and it's thus not final. Declaring variables in the smallest scope possible is a best practice in general.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Same for the loop BTW, use `for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++)`, or even better and simpler: `for (Integer id : ids)`

Comment: I wanna iterate from last to first. So for each loop won't work. I could use for or while, I just chose while.

Comment: As a side note, that `while` loop looks like a typical use case for the old `for` loop: `for(int ids.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { int id = ids.get(i); /* do stuff */ }`. Note that written that way, you can access `id` from a lambda expression within the loop’s body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have lots of ids to search, it's recommended to use a solution which does it in a single pass rather than doing a linear search for each id:

```
Map<Integer,Optional<Item>> map=ids.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, id -> Optional.empty()));
items.forEach(item ->
    map.computeIfPresent(item.getId(), (i,o)->o.isPresent()? o: Optional.of(item)));
for(ListIterator<Integer> it=ids.listIterator(ids.size()); it.hasPrevious();) {
    map.get(it.previous()).ifPresent(item -> {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

The first statement simply create a map out of the ids list, mapping each search id to an empty `Optional`.

The second statement iterates over the items using `forEach` and for each item, it checks whether there’s a mapping from its id to an empty `Optional` and will replace it with an `Optional` encapsulating the item, if there is such a mapping, all in one operation, `computeIfPresent`.

The last `for` loop iterates backwards over the `ids` list, as you wished to process them in that order and perform the action if there’s a non-empty `Optional`. Since the map was initialized with all ids found in the list, `get` will never return `null`, it will return an empty `Optional`, if the id was not found in the `items` list.

That way, assuming that the `Map`’s lookup has `O(1)` time complexity, which is the case in typical implementations, the net time complexity changed from `O(m×n)` to `O(m+n)`…

Comment: I like the idea of doing a single pass and getting all the required entries. But I need to process the entries in the order I received them in the ids list. I don't think the above code cares about ordering, right? Also, can you give some explanation of what you're trying to do in the above code? That will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Gengis Khan: it does exactly what you want. The `for` loop is iterating backwards over the `ids` list as you wished.

Answer (score 16):

You can try use something like this:

```
ids.forEach(id -> 
    list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getId() == id)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(p -> {
        // do stuff here
    });
);
```

Optional here shows that your filter method can return a empty stream, so if you call findFirst it can find one or zero elements.

Comment: replacing `findFirst()` with `findAny()` would improve performance here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359112/difference-between-findany-and-findfirst-in-java-8

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with streams and iterate backwards, you could do it this way:

```
IntStream.iterate(ids.size() - 1, i -> i - 1)
    .limit(ids.size())
    .map(ids::get) // or .map(i -> ids.get(i))
    .forEach(id -> items.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getId() == id)
        .findFirst().ifPresent(item -> {
            // do stuff
        }));
```

This code does the same as yours.

It iterates backwards, starting with a seed: `ids.size() - 1`. The initial stream of `int`s is limited in its size with `limit()`, so that there are no negative `int`s and the stream has the same size as the list of `ids`. Then, a `map()` operation converts the index to the actual `id` that is at the ith position at the `ids` list (this is done by means of invoking `ids.get(i)`). Finally, the item is searched in the `items` list the same way as in your code.

Comment: The stream operation implies an `O(n)` complexity anyway…

Comment: @Holger I mean over `ids` list

Comment: @Holger Now I see what you mean, will edit to remove that note. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to find at most one item for each given id and do something with the found item, right? A bit more performance improvement:

```
Set<Integer> idsToLookup = new HashSet<>(getIdsToLookup()); // replace list with Set

items.stream()
    .filter(e -> idsToLookup.remove(e.getId()))
    .forEach(
       /* doing something */
     );
```