# Can anyone help convert to a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

I want to convert for loop with lambda.

I just want to get the wrong result, please help convert to lambda expression, thank you.

```
The Map structure looks like this content looks like 
`{"success":"false","msg":"I got error"}`
```

```
List<Future<Map<String, Object>>> tfFuture = lists.stream().map(i -> service.submit(new what(i))).collect(Collectors.toList());

for(int i=0;i<tfFuture.size();i++){
                if(tfFuture.get(i).get().get("success").equals(Boolean.FALSE)){
                    break;
                }
                return tfFuture.get(i).get();
            }
```

I just want to get the **wrong** result

`{"success":"false","msg":"I got error"}`

Comment: Your code check only first element of the list. You don't need lambdas here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter()` and `findFirst()` and you don't need to collect either into a List :

```
return 

    lists
            .stream()
            .map(i -> service.submit(new what(i)))
            .map(Future::get)
            .filter(m -> m.get("success").equals(Boolean.FALSE))
            .findFirst().mapping(m-> m.get("success") + ":" + m.get("msg"))
            .orElse(null);
```

Here I return null as default value if no matching.

Comment: What is the benefit of using findFirst instead of findAny?

Comment: @Stefan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359112/difference-between-findany-and-findfirst-in-java-8/35359193

Comment: @Stefan returning the first element of the stream that matches.That is the OP intention in the posted code. `findAny()` doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @davidxxx I thought it was a side effect of his code, but never the less nice solution ;)