# Java 8 Stream.findFirst() makes sence only after sorting?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Streams are unordered bunches of data and their members cannot be accessed by an index.
In this case, what is the meaning of

```
Stream.findFirst()
```

method? What "first" element is meant in a stream that is not ordered? Just to find ANY element mathicng a certain condition we do have the method

```
Stream.findAny()
```

For  `Stream.findFirst()`,  accroding to the Java Doc:

*Returns an {@link Optional} describing the first element of this stream, or an empty {@code Optional} if the stream is empty.  If the stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.*

Generally, a stream does not have any order, unless explicitly sorted by the

```
Stream.sort()
```

method.

That said, `Stream.findFirst()` should only have a meaning if the stream is sorted also.

Am I right? Please help!

Comment: A stream, ordered or not, will either be empty or have a first element.

Comment: "Generally, a stream does not have any order" is false.  The documentation makes it pretty clear what happens for streams that don't have order: "any element may be returned."

Answer (score 4):

> Generally, a stream does not have any order, unless explicitly sorted by the `Stream.sort()` method.

This is not true. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering):

> Whether or not a stream has an encounter order depends on the source and the intermediate operations.

Whether a stream has an encounter order depends on the *source*, as well as the intermediate operations you used. `sorted` is only one of the ways to make an ordered stream.

The docs continues on to say that:

> Certain stream sources (such as `List` or arrays) are intrinsically ordered, whereas others (such as `HashSet`) are not.

So you can be sure that `List.stream()` will always give you an ordered stream, and `findFirst` on that stream will give you the first element of the list.

`findFirst` on an unordered stream, will, as you quoted, return any element. This means that there is no guarantee which element is returned. It *could* be the first, but it could be something else too.

Answer (score 0):

Findfirst will always find the first element the method processes after any intermediate processes are completed.  Here is one example.

```
int[] a = {1,7,3,5,6,9,8};
int res =  Arrays.stream(a).boxed().filter(i->i%2 == 0).findFirst().get();
System.out.println(res);
```

Prints

```
6
```

It is the first even number passed thru the filter.  And for the same array, the following would return 1 as there are no intermediate operations to alter the stream.

```
int res =  Arrays.stream(a).boxed().findFirst().get();
```

Compared to `findFirst`, it is likely that `findAny` would return the same element in a sequential stream.  In a parallel operation, `findFirst` would always find the first one that would be returned even in a sequential operation for the same source.  `FindAny` would not since the different threads would encounter different values during unpredictable times.

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question. "The first element it encounters" in an unordered bunch of data does not make a reasonable sence. "The first" means that the element is the first one BY one condition, not just "any". Because, for "any", we do have the method findAny. So why shall we repeat the same with findFirst?!!

Comment: The difference between findAny and FindFirst is more important during parallel operations.  FindFirst would not change its result if the same stream were repeated in  parallel or sequential mode.  That same cannot be said of findAny.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of which element will be returned.

Comment: This is why I meant that the method does make a reasonable sence, only after the stream is sorted. Otherwise you may use the findAny method - there you also do not have a guarantee of which element will be returned!

Comment: @AlexMi At this point it seems like you are just complaining about the naming of `findFirst`? Stack Overflow isn't the place for that. And no, `findFirst` is very different from `findAny`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35359112/5133585). Parallel streams and unordered streams are very different things.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you! Sure, as a more experienced person, you know better the details. But isn't it the good naming of methods one of the best developer practices anyway? Thank you once again for your kind help!